# High level internal data structures and algorithm for Hadoop FairScheduler?

Tags: java, c++, architecture, hadoop

At a high brief level what are the internals of the Hadoop FairScheduler?
Do they use priorty queues, heap for determining the time kept for each job waiting? 
Or some other technique is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is the [paper](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2009/EECS-2009-55.pdf) which describes the fair scheduler. It describes the algorithm in detail and provides benchmarks for different types of jobs. The brief summary is that it attempts to increase overall cluster throughput by running small jobs ahead or along side of larger jobs. At some level you might describe it as a priority queue but it is more complicated since it tries to place tasks that are either data or rack local and it has different tradeoffs to make. Most schedulers are better thought of as minimization algorithms since the try to decrease the amount of time it takes to get some arbitrary block of work done.